# My footer won't sit at the bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, social-networking

I can't get my footer to sit at the bottom as much as I try on blog pages: http://c3carlingford.org.au/a-nice-and-tasty-blog/

It slides up when the social media comes in...

no idea why...

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your element `noteholder masonry` is floated to the left.

Because of this, it doesn't take up space in the box model, and makes everything below it jump up to where they think the data ends.

either remove it's floating property, or use a `clear:both` div element inside it to stretch it to the height of it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your main content doesn't sit within the container correctly. If you hover over it with Firebug your footer does actually sit at the bottom of the container.

Google the clearfix method and apply it to the parent container, that will push it right down.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding something like this to your CSS:

```
#footer {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If you don't want the fixed footer, try removing `float: left;` from the `<div class="noteholder masonry">`

Comment: i doubt that this is the effect he is looking for. he wants a sticky footer that will stay at the bottom both when the content is too short and when it's longer.